# Page Loading Speed

Tags: pagespeed

I have a 2 web sites that are using the same code but the domain of each one is different. The average time of each of them for page load is different, what may cause it? Also, for the same website there are different times for the same page type with different content, but the difference is huge - one is 13% above average and the second is 85%, what can be the reason?

Comment: Your question is very vague and broad. I don't think you're asking this at the right place here on SO. We will have to know what's the technology you used to power your websites, what's the hardware specs, and even the access to your source code in order to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

You state they serve different content, depending what this content is, this is probably not going to cause that much of an issue. Obviously if one is serving static text while the other is serving a video stream, you'll get a noticeable difference, but let us assume this isn't the case.

If you boil down down the levels far enough, it usually comes down to physical hardware, where are your websites hosted?

***(I will try to avoid too much detail)***

**Scenario 1:** One website is getting a *significantly* larger number of requests the the other - the underlying hardware of where your website lives may be under more strain than it likes and requests can get sort of queued in the thread pool. Hence waiting longer than usual for your request to come through.

**Scenario 2:** Different hardware specifications on your hosting - if one site has more RAM, or maybe supports multi-threading etc. Then realistically it will have better performance.

**Scenario 3:** Shared and dedicated hosting - your site(s) could be using shared hosting, this means the hardware isn't dedicated to just you, it will also be serving other processors for other users, this would be more intermittent though and you shouldn't see a *constant* issue with your performance.

**Scenario 4:** Domain providers - you say they are using different domains, are they different providers? They may go through different name servers. They may offer different pricing plans if you're paying for the hosting with the domain name, ultimately offering better performance. This list goes on.

I could provide more scenarios but it's a bit unrealistic for me to keep going without knowing the setup of your sites, provide more details and we can help find a more specific answer.

However, I hope this helps you understand a little more...